# Displaying servlet output

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I have one servlet which connects to remote unix machine and executes one command which takes lot of time,
I need to display output of that unix command continuously on webpage, I am able to fetch the output from unix machine and able to continuously display it in console, but not able to display it in web page at the same time as query is executing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for asynchronous servlets (specification version 3.0).